# Mysterious message from the NoSlaves™ Calculator Co

Tags: lateral-thinking, number-sequence, enigmatic-puzzle

So my son is starting to show an interest in mathematics, and being the awesome dad that I am, I decided to buy him a basic calculator. Being the cheapskate that I am, I ordered the cheapest one I could find, which happened to be from ***NoSlaves™ Calculator Co.*** <sup>(*When only the cheapest calculator will do, make sure you buy from NoSlaves™, where we lovingly craft our calculators to almost adequate levels of quality, and totally don't use any slave labour... at all.*)</sup>

Unfortunately (and surprisingly), when it arrived, there seemed to be something wrong with it... I plugged in a few quick test calculations:

```
1 + 1 = 1
4 + 3 = 9
8 - 3 + 5 = 6
24 + 51 = 84
50 - 74 + 39 = 98
```

Now, I like to complain as much as the next guy, so I went hunting through the instruction manual for the company's phone number. However, on the warranty and support information page, I found the following, scrawled in a strange, dark reddish, congealed ink of some sort:

> 2 - 3 + 4 = ?
> 80 - 17 = ?
> 4 - 1 + 2 - _ = ?

Curious, I entered in the calculations... I didn't know what the underscore meant, so just ignored it, but regardless, the results were even more broken than my initial test calculations. By this stage I was bored, so I shrugged it off and went to bed.

Three weeks later, being the brilliant detective I am, I suddenly realised that the hand written message carried a cleverly concealed secret message. I immediately phoned the police department and was hailed as a hero.

**What was wrong with the calculator? And, what was the mysterious hidden message?**

Comment: strange, dark-reddish congealed ink...? You don't mean... blood? O_O

Comment: "Totally don't use any slave labor at all." Help, I'm stuck in a calculator factory.

Comment: "Three weeks later, being the brilliant detective I am" *Folks in PSE solve it in 5 hours* lol

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem with the calculator is:

> It adds/subtracts the segments of the display, not the numbers.
> So, 4 + 3 is indeed equal to 9
>
> [image]

The hidden message, then, is:

> HELP, all in capitals. The underscore in the last sum is the bottom line segment on the display.
>
> Example for the first sum :
> [image: Example for the first sum]
> http://www.uize.com/examples/seven-segment-display.html
>
> Since it's clearly been written in blood, something foul is afoot at the calculator factory

Sorry, don't have access to much by way of image-editing stuff atm, so can't do the pretty pictures.

Comment: You don't think that message was written by a *slave*, do you? O_o